# Python ICMP packets in raw sockets

Tags: python-3.x

So i'm wanting to send spoofed ICMP packets, but when I open up Wireshark and look at the packets they don't resemble at all what I wan't and it doesn't even show it's an ICMP packet it just says ipv4. Help would be greatly appreciated! 
P.S. I know what Scapy is.
Operating Sys: Win. 10,
Python Vrs: 3.5. [This is what Wireshark Shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVfZw.png)

```
import socket
from struct import *
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)

def icmp():
    global icmp_p
    type = 8
    code = 0
    cs = 0
    id = 0x0001
    seq = 13
    icmp_p = pack("!BBHHH", type, code, cs, id, seq)
    return icmp_p

def ip_header():
    global ip_p
    ip_ihl = 5
    ip_ver = 5
    ip_tos = 0
    ip_tot_len = 0
    ip_id = 54321
    ip_frag_off = 0
    ip_ttl = 8
    ip_proto = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP
    ip_check = 1
    ip_saddr = socket.inet_aton ( "1.1.1.1" )
    ip_daddr = socket.inet_aton ( "192.168.1.3" )
    ip_ihl_ver = (ip_ver << 4) + ip_ihl
    ip_p = pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_ihl_ver, ip_tos, ip_tot_len, ip_id, ip_frag_off, ip_ttl, ip_proto, ip_check, ip_saddr, ip_daddr)
    return ip_p

def packet():
    global packet
    packet = ip_p + icmp_p
    print(packet)

icmp()
ip_header()
packet()

while True:
    time.sleep(.1)
    s.sendto(packet, ("192.168.1.3", 80))
```

Comment: *I open up Wireshark and look at the packets they don't resemble at all what I wan't* - and, uhh, what do you want?

Comment: Wan't them to be icmp packets with all the headers I set